# Wordpress get URL of the page which the given template is assigned to

Tags: wordpress

Does any one knows how to get URL of the page which the given template is assigned to.

**Ex:**

Template name: `tpl_gallery.php` (Question)

Url: `gallery.html` (Answer should be)

**More explanation:**

```
function getTplPageURL( $TEMPLATE_NAME ) {
    $url;

    //Code which i need

    return $url;
}
```

Comment: $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ?

Comment: what u want to achieve exactly...?? make your question more clear

Comment: @Gopalrathore Please check my explantion. i need to write a function which should return url when some one pass the template file name.

Answer (score 5):

I changed this function a bit because it did not work for me:

```
function getTplPageURL($TEMPLATE_NAME){
    $url = null;
    $pages = get_pages(array(
        'meta_key' => '_wp_page_template',
        'meta_value' => $TEMPLATE_NAME
    ));
    if(isset($pages[0])) {
        $url = get_page_link($pages[0]->ID);
    }
    return $url;
}
```

Now works for me fine on WordPress 4.9.4

**Usage:**

```
echo getTplPageURL( 'page-templates/tpl-about.php' );
```

Comment: Also note that if your template file is in a sub-folder, remember to call that folder name. 
`...
'meta_value' => sub-folder/$TEMPLATE_NAME
...
;
`
You also need to call to make sure you call the full name file, the '.php' included. I hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

What it sounds like you're after is get_page_link(), which is described in more detail here:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_page_link

If you use this inside the loop of your template it will give you the URL of the page you're on.

```
<?php get_page_link(); ?>
```

edit: okay, I misunderstood the request. Here's another approach based on this answer from the WP StackExchange: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/39657

```
function getTplPageURL($TEMPLATE_NAME){
    $url;

    //Code which i need

     $pages = query_posts(array(
         'post_type' =>'page',
         'meta_key'  =>'_wp_page_template',
         'meta_value'=> $TEMPLATE_NAME
     ));

     // cycle through $pages here and either grab the URL
     // from the results or do get_page_link($id) with 
     // the id of the page you want 

     $url = null;
     if(isset($pages[0])) {
         $url = get_page_link($pages[0]['id']);
     }
     return $url;
 }
```

Comment: i need to get url any where in the website. not only inside it's template.

Comment: I haven't tested this code, so I apologize in advance if it's off the mark - but I hope it gives you enough of an idea to proceed on your own

Comment: On line with getting link and call post id from the first element of pages array - need use object way: 

`$url = get_page_link($pages[0]->ID);`, because `$pages[0]` return `WP_Post` object.

Comment: And calling `query_posts` redefined global query to any current page. And best use separate instance of WP_Query locally inside that function: `(new WP_Query())->query(array(...`

Answer (score 0):

### Working example: 2022

thanks to TJ Nicolaides

```
echo getTplPageURL( 'templates/tpl-about.php' ) ; //path to template file

// in function.php
function getTplPageURL( $TEMPLATE_NAME ) {
    $pages = query_posts( [
        'post_type'  => 'page',
        'meta_key'   => '_wp_page_template',
        'meta_value' => $TEMPLATE_NAME
    ] );
    $url   = '';
    if ( isset( $pages[0] ) ) {
        $array = (array) $pages[0];
        $url   = get_page_link( $array['ID'] );
    }

    return $url;
}
```